# How to dynamically allocate an array of integers in C

Tags: c, arrays

A portion of my C code is shown below.

```
int data[10]={1,3,6,8,1,7,9,1,1,1}; 
b=10;
int out[b];
process(data, &b, out);
alpha (out, b);
```

data and out are  int arrays. The function process takes the array data whose length is pointed by b (=10) and performs mathematical operation and then returns an array out whose length is then again returned by b (unknown and hence required to be dynamically allocated). Then the array out is sent with function alpha. Right now the function alpha always sends out[10] since b has been declared as 10 in second line of code. How can I allocate array out dynamically so that it contains only valid data returned after function process.

Comment: With `malloc`...

Comment: I am new to c and hence don't know how to use malloc

Comment: You are not required to use all the elements of `out` in your `alpha` function, since you are passing the dimensions of the array (`b`) just stay between those values: `[0 ... b)`

Answer (score 7):

You need to know the difference between dynamic and static allocations.

There are 3 alternatives:

- **Static allocation:**

You need to know in advance the array length. It must be a number and not a variable:

```
int out[10];
```

Array is **static** and is only locally scoped. So if you do:

```
function do_something()
{
   int out[10];
}
```

you can't use the *out* array outside the function. But you can define *out*
outside and send it like this:

```
function do_something(int* out)
{
   // do things
}
...
{
   int out[10];
   do_something(out);
}
```

- **Automatic allocation**

When you do

```
int b = 100;
int out[b];
```

(which won't compile on gcc without the -std=c99 or -std=c11 flag), you get an automatic variable, which is very convenient if you don't use *out* out of scope, but can be a bit dangerous. The resulting array is generated in the **Stack**, and is destroyed when it goes out of scope (which is why it can get you into trouble if you use it freely). See 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html

We suggest you use:

- **Dynamic allocation**

Where the array is generated on the **Heap** and you are responsible to clean it up when you're done with it. The down side is you need to clean it up yourself. The up side is you can use pass it around and use it anywhere.

```
int b=100;
int* out = (int*) malloc(b * sizeof(int));
// do things with out
free(out);
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:**
Do not change the value of the **pointer** *out*. If you do, then you won't free the right amount of memory. A nice thing to do is to copy the pointer, and use the copied address for free:

```
   int b=100;
   int* out = (int*) malloc(b * sizeof(int));
   int* out_copy = out;
   // do things with out. don't touch out_copy
   free(out_copy);
```

Comment: C99 does, actually. It's called *Variable Length Array* (VLA). You cannot allocate it inside the function and return it to be used outside the function of course, nevertheless, your opening statement is wrong.

Comment: You're right. But then there are scoping problems. I'm not sure a beginner should wrestle with those... Anyway, I've added a clarification.

Comment: That's not the point. The pure statement is wrong, and the suggestion "Don't use static allocation" is pointless. If the code doesn't compile, then the OP will obviously not be using it. In fact, the OP is clearly stating this fact in the question, so I can't see how telling him/her to avoid what they're **not** doing is helpful in any manner.

Comment: What a nice cast :)

Comment: `won't compile on old version of C.` The only Standard is `C11`. This means that if one should compile with an **OLD** standard knows already that. So, yes the OP should use `int out[b];`.

Comment: Take a look at github and check how may projects there already conform with the new standard. Hint: not nearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *out;
out=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

This will produce array `out` of `integer` type with size 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need `out` to be a pointer - not an array - and you need to pass a pointer to `out` to the function, just like you do with `b`.

Example:

```
void f(int **a, int *size)
{
    *a = malloc(23 * sizeof(**a));
    *size = 23;
}


/* ... */
int *p = NULL;
int b = 0;
f(&p, &b);
/* 'p' has been allocated and 'b' has its size. */
```

Comment: I don't get u. Can u apply the same example to my code and then reply. What i know  from my limited knowledge of c is that an array once decalred is always a pointer

Comment: You forgot to call `free()`

Comment: @Habib.Khan An array is never a pointer. In many contexts, for instance when you pass it to a function, there is an implicit *conversion* into a pointer to the array's first element. (Your `process(data, &b, out);` is exactly the same as `process(&data[0], &b, &out[0]);`) I would recommend that you invest in a good book.